# Can't add element to ArrayList using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a child called numbers on Firebase database.

[image: child numbers]

in my code, I don't understand if inside the onDataChange() method, listNumber.size() return 4. But outside onDataChange() value of listNumber.size() return 0.

[image: my code:]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, post it as a formatted text instead.

Comment: Essentially, you are getting the same result if you moved that bottom line to above the Firebase call. Best to learn & understand how asynchronous code works

Answer (score 3):

onDataChange is a listener, it is not called immediately, it is called after Firebase has returned data.

So the execution order looks like this:

1. Make request to Firebase and you add listeners. Data is not present.
2. Execute code after request (`//result = 0`)
3. Firebase has returned data, so your listeners are being called (`//result = 4`)

Answer (score 1):

This is asynchronous programming. 
Firebase executes its methods asynchronously , it does not waits for the data as fetching the data from the server may take a lot of time. So, at the time you call your variable outside onDataChanged method it is not assigned any value.
Thus, it holds null.

You can take the statement to the onDataChanged method. You can also make a model class with setter and getter methods.
Set the value of the variable by calling the setter of the model class inside the onDataChanged and call the getter method after the onDataChanged to get back the value.